# How to get random value out of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array called `$ran = array(1,2,3,4);`

I need to get a random value out of this array and store it in a variable, how can I do this?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You can also do just:

```
$k = array_rand($array);
$v = $array[$k];
```

This is the way to do it when you have an associative array.

Comment: according to this [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php#105265) `array_rand` is not as random as it should be

Comment: Or you can require [this package](https://github.com/freekmurze/array-functions) and use `array_rand_value`

Comment: Since PHP 7.1, [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) uses the Mersenne Twister generator: [rand() aliased to mt_rand() and srand() aliased to mt_srand()](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases). In practice it should now be good enough.

Answer (score 39):

PHP provides a function just for that: array_rand()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

```
$ran = array(1,2,3,4);
$randomElement = $ran[array_rand($ran, 1)];
```

Comment: The default value of second argument of `array_rand` function is `1` so don't need to write it.

Answer (score 27):

```
$value = $array[array_rand($array)];
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use [mt_rand()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

```
$random = $ran[mt_rand(0, count($ran) - 1)];
```

This comes in handy as a function as well if you need the value

```
function random_value($array, $default=null)
{
    $k = mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1);
    return isset($array[$k])? $array[$k]: $default;
}
```

Comment: Should be mt_rand(0, 3) as there are only 4 items. More correctly though: $array[mt_rand(0, count($array)]

Comment: Err, I think you meant mt_rand(0, count($ran) - 1)

Comment: according to php comments `array_rand` is not as random as it should be, so `mt_rand` is preferred

Comment: What's the point in the whole `isset` part? This would fail for associative arrays anyway.

Comment: i don't know why, but when using `mt_rand` instead of `rand` in this case seems to prefer some items more than the others

Comment: since PHP 7.1 array_rand uses Mersenne Twister algorithm http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Despite this answer being 10 years old, one could obtain the array keys and *then* get a random key from that array. If you do `$keys = array_keys($array);` and then `$key = mt_rand(0, count($keys) - 1);`, the variable `$key` will have a random index from the array `$keys`, which returns a key to be used for the `$array`. Something like `return $array[$keys[$key]];`. This will work for associative, numeric and mixed arrays. Try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/455d7a75d1b0951e29adf9a319e7da3678468ca2 (remove the type hinting for compatibility with PHP 5.0 and older)

Answer (score 20):

You could use the array_rand function to select a random key from your array like below.

```
$array = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
echo $array[array_rand($array, 1)];
```

---

or you could use the rand and count functions to select a random index.

```
$array = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
echo $array[rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
```

Answer (score 13):

Derived from Laravel [`Collection::random()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php):

```
function array_random($array, $amount = 1)
{
    $keys = array_rand($array, $amount);

    if ($amount == 1) {
        return $array[$keys];
    }

    $results = [];
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $results[] = $array[$key];
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Usage:

```
$items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'lorem'=>'ipsum'];

array_random($items); // 'bar'
array_random($items, 2); // ['foo', 'ipsum']
```

A few notes:

- `$amount` has to be less than or equal to `count($array)`.
- `array_rand()` doesn't shuffle keys (since PHP 5.2.10, see [48224](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48224)), so your picked items will always be in original order. Use `shuffle()` afterwards if needed.

Documentation: [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

**edit:** The Laravel function has noticeably grown since then, see Laravel 5.4's [`Arr::random()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php). Here is something more elaborate, derived from the grown-up Laravel function:

```
function array_random($array, $number = null)
{
    $requested = ($number === null) ? 1 : $number;
    $count = count($array);

    if ($requested > $count) {
        throw new \RangeException(
            "You requested {$requested} items, but there are only {$count} items available."
        );
    }

    if ($number === null) {
        return $array[array_rand($array)];
    }

    if ((int) $number === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    $keys = (array) array_rand($array, $number);

    $results = [];
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $results[] = $array[$key];
    }

    return $results;
}
```

A few highlights:

- Throw exception if there are not enough items available
- `array_random($array, 1)` returns an array of one item ([#19826](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19826))
- Support value "0" for the number of items ([#20439](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20439))

Answer (score 13):

Another approach through flipping array to get direct value.

Snippet

```
$array = [ 'Name1' => 'John', 'Name2' => 'Jane', 'Name3' => 'Jonny' ];
$val = array_rand(array_flip($array));
```

`array_rand` return key not value. So, we're flipping value as key.

**Note:** 
PHP key alway be an unique key, so when array is flipped, duplicate value as a key will be overwritten.

Comment: Why not just do `$array[array_rand($array)];`?

Comment: @rinogo It's works too, This already answered above. This is little bit different from your answer,   `array_flip` remove duplicate as key then give result... Mean no duplicate!

Comment: To escape duplicate keys you can use this syntax (In the second row): 
`$array = [ 'Name1' => 'John', 'Name2' => 'Jane', 'Name3' => 'Jane' ];
$val = array_rand(array_flip(array_unique($array)));`

Comment: I like this approach as it allows for a simple single line code with an array declared directly on-the-fly inside it, eg `array_rand(array_flip(array('ad-1.jpg','ad-2.gif','ad-3.png')))`

Answer (score 10):

The `array_rand` function seems to have an uneven distribution on large arrays, not every array item is equally likely to get picked. Using [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on the array and then taking the first element doesn't have this problem:

```
$myArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// Random shuffle
shuffle($myArray);

// First element is random now
$randomValue = $myArray[0];
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra computational "work" just to get a single random element, though. The other answers that use `mt_rand()` are probably better suited to the task.

Comment: Depends on what your needs are, I suppose. In my case, distribution was very important and the computational overhead was not.

Answer (score 6):

```
$rand = rand(1,4);
```

or, for arrays specifically:

```
$array = array('a value', 'another value', 'just some value', 'not some value');
$rand = $array[ rand(0, count($array)-1) ];
```

Comment: You would never get the first item in this list and you would go outside the array with 4

Comment: The first $rand is about values. The original array has values ranging from 1 to 4. The second $rand is about array keys, 0 to 3.

Answer (score 6):

On-liner:

```
echo $array[array_rand($array,1)]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236022/1213708 answered 7 years earlier?

Comment: It was edited in 17, but yeah looks like the same approach

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have to get 2 values what are objects. I share this simple solution.

```
$ran = array("a","b","c","d");
$ranval = array_map(function($i) use($ran){return $ran[$i];},array_rand($ran,2));
```

Answer (score 3):

One line: `$ran[rand(0, count($ran) - 1)]`

Answer (score 3):

This will work nicely with in-line arrays. Plus, I think things are tidier and more reusable when wrapped up in a function.

```
function array_rand_value($a) {
    return $a[array_rand($a)];
}
```

Usage:

```
array_rand_value(array("a", "b", "c", "d"));
```

On PHP < 7.1.0, `array_rand()` uses `rand()`, so you wouldn't want to this function for anything related to security or cryptography. On PHP 7.1.0+, use this function without concern since [`rand()` has been aliased to `mt_rand()`](https://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases).

Answer (score 3):

I needed one line version for short array:

```
($array = [1, 2, 3, 4])[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)]
```

or if array is fixed:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4][mt_rand(0, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your selection have any security implications? If so, use `random_int()` and `array_keys()`. (`random_bytes()` is PHP 7 only, but there is a [polyfill for PHP 5](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat)).

```
function random_index(array $source)
{
    $max = count($source) - 1;
    $r = random_int(0, $max);
    $k = array_keys($source);
    return $k[$r];
}
```

Usage:

```
$array = [
    'apple' =>   1234,
    'boy'   =>   2345,
    'cat'   =>   3456,
    'dog'   =>   4567,
    'echo'  =>   5678,
    'fortune' => 6789
];
$i = random_index($array);
var_dump([$i, $array[$i]]);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/1joB1

Answer (score 2):

Use rand() to get random number to echo random key. In ex: 0 - 3

```
$ran = array(1,2,3,4);
echo $ran[rand(0,3)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing my answer off of @ÓlafurWaage's function. I tried to use it but was running into reference issues when I had tried to modify the return object. I updated his function to pass and return by reference. The new function is:

```
function &random_value(&$array, $default=null)
{
    $k = mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1);
    if (isset($array[$k])) {
        return $array[$k];
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

For more context, see my question over at [Passing/Returning references to object + changing object is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702536/passing-returning-references-to-object-changing-object-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Get random values from an array.

```
function random($array)
{
    /// Determine array is associative or not
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $givenArrIsAssoc = array_keys($keys) !== $keys;

    /// if array is not associative then return random element
    if(!$givenArrIsAssoc){
        return $array[array_rand($array)];
    }

    /// If array is associative then 
    $keys = array_rand($array, $number);
    $results = [];
    foreach ((array) $keys as $key) {
        $results[] = $array[$key];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mt_srand` usage example

if one needs to pick a random row from a text but same all the time based on something

```
$rows = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $text));
mt_srand($item_id);
$row = $rows[rand(0, count($rows ) - 1)];
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to getting **Randdom value form Array**.

```
$color_array =["red","green","blue","light_orange"];
$color_array[rand(0,3)
```

now every time you will get different colors from **Array**.

Answer (score -5):

You get a random number out of an array as follows:

```
$randomValue = $rand[array_rand($rand,1)];
```

Comment: array_rand() returns a random key, not a random value.