# Passing/Returning references to object + changing object is not working

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I am using [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643438/86421) from [How to get random value out of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643431/how-to-get-random-value-out-of-an-array) to write a function that returns a random item from the array. I modified it to [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [return a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work. Any modifications to the returned object do not persist. What am I doing wrong?

I'm on PHP 5.4 if that makes a difference (Don't ask).

```
function &random_value(&$array, $default=null)
{
    $k = mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1);
    $return = isset($array[$k])? $array[$k]: $default;
    return $return;
}
```

Usage...

```
$companies = array();
$companies[] = array("name" => "Acme Co",  "employees"=> array( "John", "Jane" ));
$companies[] = array("name" => "Inotech",  "employees"=> array( "Bill", "Michael" ));

$x = &random_value($companies);
$x["employees"][] = "Donald";
var_dump($companies);
```

Output...

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(7) "Acme Co"
    'employees' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "John"
      [1] =>
      string(4) "Jane"
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(7) "Inotech"
    'employees' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(4) "Bill"
      [1] =>
      string(7) "Michael"
    }
  }
}
```

I even copied and pasted the examples from the documentation and none of those worked either. They all output `null`.

Comment: Client requirement! I can only tell them so many times in so many ways that being on 5.4 is a terrible idea.

Comment: I know, you said don't ask so of course I had to.

Comment: Maybe the client will respond to [scary graphs](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Why are you using references? Are you just trying to return a random array from `$companies`?

Comment: @bishop Needs more red! I actually showed them that and it hasn't changed their mind yet.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I need to modify the object after it is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator creates an implicit copy, which breaks the reference chain. Use an explicit `if... else`:

```
function &random_value(&$array, $default=null)
{
    $k = mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1);
    if (isset($array[$k])) {
        return $array[$k];
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

As to why, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) now state:

> Note: Please note that the ternary operator is an expression, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP versions.

See also [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70857) where the ternary operator actually returns by reference in a `foreach` context, when it shouldn't.

Comment: I just tried that. I returns the same incorrect result.

Comment: It works for me too! I will have to read up on why the ternary operator does that. I wouldn't expect that to happen (obviously!). Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Your function still returns the whole array. He only wants one element doesn't he?

Comment: It's how the zval copy-on-write processing happens in the engine, at least up through 5.6.  See also [this post](http://fabien.potencier.org/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not.html).  I'm not sure what if anything changed in 7. (I doubt it.)

Comment: @Jaime: returns only one element for me and [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/f7cn9).  Note that each element is an array of two keys: `name` and `employees`.

Comment: Your 3v4l changed the code from OP, I was just running what he pasted. You are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a better function aspect than @bishop as I have just consumed an enormous lunch, however this works:

```
$x =& $companies[array_rand($companies)];
$x["employees"][] = "Donald";
var_dump($companies);
```

Comment: I would recommend this approach also, but I suppose the mitigating factor is the use of `$default` for null values, eg: `$companies = [ [], ['name' => 'Foo', 'employees' => []] ];`