# Parsing multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a CSV file that I am parsing using PHP. However, the output looks as follows:

```
Array(
    [0] => URL
    [1] => Value
    [2] => Author
)

Array(
    [0] => URL
    [1] => Value
    [2] => Author
)

Array(
    [0] => URL
    [1] => Value
    [2] => Author
)
```

And so on...

How can I parse each of these individually and/or display only one at random? I've tried using array_values, but that seems to output all arrays, not just one.   Any suggestions? Feel free to let me know if there is anything else I can provide. Thanks guys.

Edit: Added some code if it helps - pretty basic.

```
//CSV to array and parse
function parseCSV() {
    $file = fopen('feeds/data.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        //$line is an array of the csv elements
        $arr = $line;

        $url = array_values($arr)[2];
        $author = array_values($arr)[1];

        print_r($arr);
    }

    fclose($file);      
}//end
```

Comment: `array[0]` ? or something like that ?

Comment: What O/P you expected ?

Comment: is not really clear what is the problem you should show us your parsing code as well

Comment: Added a bit of code it it helps. My problem is I am trying to display only one array's values at a time - even better if I can find out how to display a random one each time.

Comment: Can we assume that one of these arrays is produced from a single line from your csv file? _Question is Unclear, more imformation/code would be useful if you want any actual help_

Comment: The CSV file is in 3 separate columns. Seems to be an array for each column's value(s).

Comment: `$url = $arr[0];`

Comment: In fact ditch `$arr` and use `$url = $line[0]; $value = $line[1]; $author = $line[2];`

Comment: `fgetcsv` returns you One line from the file each time round the loop in an array called `$line` Its then a simple task to get the individual columns out of the `$line` array

Comment: Better add some more code and show us what you are doing with this data once you get hold of it

Comment: I used your examples and it is returning every value of a column rather than just one. Will add some code once I figure it out a bit more.

Comment: Your question seems to have little to do with csv. You are just looking for how to pick a random element from an array (of arrays). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643431/how-to-get-random-value-out-of-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

Class CsvRandomLine
{
    private $line_count=0;
    private $random_element;
    private $handle;
    private $csv_arr;

    function __construct($file='feeds/data.csv')   
    {
        $this->handle = fopen($file, "r");

         $this->sort_one_element();
    }


    //CSV to array and parse
    function randomLine() 
    {
        $i = 0;

        // move pointer to the sorted line
        while($i < $this->random_element)
        {
          $line = fgets($this->handle);
          $i++;
        }        

        $line = fgetcsv($this->handle);


        //add element to $csv_arr with $url and  $author
        $this->csv_arr=array(
                            "url"    =>  $line[2],
                            "author" =>  $line[1]
                        );


    }//end


    function get($property)
    {
        return $this->csv_arr[$property];
    }


    function sort_one_element()
    {
        if($this->line_count!=0)
        {
            $max = $this->line_count;
        }
        else
        {

            $max = $this->countLines();
        }

        $max--;

        $n = rand( 0 , $max );    

        //echo $n;

        $this->random_element = $n;

        rewind($this->handle);        

        $this->randomLine();    


    }


    function countLines()
    {
        $linecount=0;
        while( fgets($this->handle) !== FALSE )
        {
          $linecount++;
        }

        $this->line_count=$linecount;

        return $linecount;            
    }


    function __destruct()
    {
        fclose($this->handle);
    }

}    


// How to use the class:


$csv_r = new CsvRandomLine();
//Construct automatic sort the first element

echo $csv_r->get("author");
echo '<br>';
echo $csv_r->get("url");

echo '<hr>';

//Sorting another element
$csv_r->sort_one_element();

echo $csv_r->get("author");
echo '<br>';
echo $csv_r->get("url");
```

Comment: This seems to work great, but only when I remove the fact that it is inside a function.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to call the function in the code above.
Now added:
parseCSV();

Comment: Example of csv(feed/data.csv):

1,Alexandre,www.samurai.com
2,Captain Comando,www.capitaincomando.com
3,Puffgirl,www.powerpuffgirls.com
4,Opa Gangnam Style,www.opagangnamstyle.com

Comment: Change         $this->csv_arr=array(
                            "url"    =>  $line[2],
                            "author" =>  $line[1]
                        );
to modify or add cloumns of the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would load the array with all the records on the csv file (the first `$line` read is always the header of the csv document, and I would use it to create the result assoc_array keys), then if you want to display one (the first of the result array) or a random (just use `array_rand()`).

Just a dirty example

```
$result = [];
$keys = null;
while(($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false){
    if($keys === null){
        $keys = $line;
        continue;
    }
    $row = [];
    foreach($keys as $position => $key){
        $row[$key] = $line[$position];
    }
    $result[] = $row;
}

// here you will have $result with all the records and you can get the first or do whaterver you want to show just one
```

In case you need just the bare data and no an assoc_array you could do

```
$result = [];
$keys = null;
while(($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false){
    if($keys === null){
        $keys = $line;
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = $line;
}
```

// here you will have $result (raw data) and $keys (the header of the csv)

Comment: Of course you could just do `$all_lines[] = $line;` in the loop and save writing all that code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem with that is that you will not have an assoc, you will have $all_lines[0] to be the header of the csv, and everything else to be a not assoc_array with the data payload.

Comment: This gives me a more readable format, but seems to be a multidimensional array now

Comment: @user1721449 I thought that was what you wanted, if you just want the raw output line by line you could do soemthing using RiggsFolly suggestion. I will update the answer