# PHP - Rand value from arrays

Tags: php

I have 3 arrays with different values.

I select a random value from each array and adding the value to another array.

For some reason a value from the first array gets added everytime!

```
 $targets = 3;
 $singles = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
 $doubles = array('Double 1', 'Double 2', 'Double 3', 'Double 4');
 $trebles = array('Treble 1', 'Treble 2', 'Treble 3', 'Treble 4');
 $tasks = array('Any Red', 'Any Green', 'Any Treble', 'Any Double');

 $game_card = array();

for($i=0; $i < $targets; $i++)
{
    $single_number = array_rand($singles);
    $game_card[] = $single_number;

    $double_number = array_rand($doubles);
    $game_card[] = $double_number;

    $treble_number = array_rand($trebles);
    $game_card[] = $treble_number;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `array_rand()` returns something other than what you think it should?  Like the key maybe?

Comment: array_rand returns the KEY not the VALUE. (and key here is just the index, which happens to be an integer, which looks like the values of the first array)

Comment: All of your arrays will return 0,1,2 or 3.

Comment: How do I use the value instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get random value out of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643431/how-to-get-random-value-out-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

[array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns the KEY not the VALUE. And the key here is just the index, which happens to be an integer, which looks like the values of the first array.

So what you want is:

```
$single_number = array_rand($singles);
$game_card[] = $singles[$single_number];

$double_number = array_rand($doubles);
$game_card[] = $doubles[$double_number];

....
```