# php - how to randomizing items in array

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array , suppose this  :

```
$a=array("a","b","c","d","e");
```

I want to make items in my array get randomize , I want to randomize the items inside /. for example I get this after ward :

```
$a=array("d","a","b","e","c");
```

I tried to use shuffle but it doesn't do what I want

How can I make my array randomize ?

Comment: How are you using `shuffle`? Note that it shuffles the array in-place, so you shouldn't assign the result to anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get random value out of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643431/how-to-get-random-value-out-of-an-array)

Comment: Edit; `shuffle($a);  var_dump($a);` https://3v4l.org/LonC5

Comment: try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_array_rand.asp) ... i think its basically the same thing.

Comment: From the `shuffle()` page: "This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used `shuffle` function

```
  $a=array("a","b","c","d","e");

    shuffle($a);
    print_r($a);
```

for more details about `shuffle` read [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Answer (score -1):

shuffle() you just need to pass your array in shuffle function.

```
<?php
$a=array("a","b","c","d","e");

shuffle($a);
print_r($a);
?>
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_array_shuffle.asp