# how do I select one word from array list like this one?

Tags: php, arrays, json, random

I have this

```
$words = array("Car", "Dog", "Ship");
```

now I want to randomly select only one word, please help!

Comment: Have you looked at tutorials on the topic? How is JSON related? Google `shuffle PHP`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get random value out of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643431/how-to-get-random-value-out-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work.

```
  $words[rand(0, sizeof($words) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_rand() function to get more than one random index.
array_rand(array, number)

```
<?php
    $words=array("Car", "Dog", "Ship");
    $random_keys=array_rand($words,3);
    echo $words[$random_keys[0]]."<br>";
    echo $words[$random_keys[1]]."<br>";
    echo $words[$random_keys[2]];
?>
```