# php select a random array value within while loop and assign it to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, random, while-loop, shuffle

How can I get and assign a random array value from array inside a while loop to a variable?

Code

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mem_id FROM members WHERE mem_id NOT IN (SELECT ref_referral FROM referrals)");
$stmt-> execute();

$rec = array();
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
  $rec[] = $f;
}
print_r($rec);
```

The above code returns this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 3
            [0] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 4
            [0] => 4
        )

)
```

Now if I want to take one value from either of `2,3,4` randomly and assign it to a variable say `$randomValue = $randomValueFromArray`, how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643438/3859027

Comment: @Kevin I already tried `echo $rec[array_rand($rec)];` and it returns `Notice: Array to string conversion in`. I also tried `echo $f[array_rand($f)];` and it returns all the values like this `234` instead of returning one single value randomly. What should I do?

Comment: make your array flat, so that you can use random functions for array. so push single elements `$rec[] = $f['mem_id'];`

Comment: you can use `array_rand()` [demo](https://3v4l.org/vjmKL)